# hadoop mapreduce programming if condition

Tags: hadoop, if-statement, mapreduce

I have wrote the below code, which is not comparing if block it keep on going into else block.
Please go through that and check if you found any discrepancy.

please help on that

```
    public class ReduceIncurance extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException

    {

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String[] input = values.toString().split(",");

        for (String val : input) {
            System.out.println("first:" + val);
            if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("Residential")) {
                System.out.println(val);
                count++;
                sum += count;
            } else {
                System.out.println("into elsee part");
                count++;
                sum += count;
            }

            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. what is the issue?

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958593/how-to-iterate-among-text-in-the-for-loop-and-find-count-of-a-particular-text-in?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: what is the output you are expecting. Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    int count=0;

    for (Text val : values)
    {
        if (val.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Residential"))
        {
            count ++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("into elsee part");
        }
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
}
```

This will give you the count of value 'residential' under each key.

Issue is in this code `String[] input = values.toString().split(",");`. `Iterable<Text>` cannot be converted to `String[]` like this.

Comment: You cannot do .get() for Text

Answer (score 0):

For a specific key you need to iterate through the values. You dont need to store them to String[].

Try this

```
public class ReduceIncurance extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (Text val : values) {
        String[] input = val.toString().split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Residential")) {
            System.out.println(val);
            count++;
            sum += count;
        } else {
            System.out.println("into elsee part");
            count++;
            sum += count;
        }
       }
     context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
   }
 }
}
```

I dont still understand why you are incrementing sum and count in both if and else block.